# how can i can make my wpf textbox retrieve some data in the excel

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have a program that user will input the details based on the excel. How can I make my program retrieve the data from the excel.. I'm searching so hard in the google and other site and didn't find any sample..
the scenario is that the user will provide number in identifier textbox, after that the program will retrieve the data in the excel based on the identifier provided by the user.. identifer is the column A of excel..

Xaml

```
    <controls:MetroWindow x:Class='IMDC_ePub_Maker.View.MainView'
                      xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation'
                      xmlns:x='http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml'
                      xmlns:controls='clr-namespace:MahApps.Metro.Controls;assembly=MahApps.Metro'
                      xmlns:viewModel='clr-namespace:IMDC_ePub_Maker.ViewModel'
                      BorderThickness='1'
                      BorderBrush='#9b7b56'
                      Title='{Binding ProgramExe}'
                      Height='411.445'
                      Width='572.667'
                      ResizeMode="NoResize"
                      WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen"
                      Closing='MetroWindow_Closing'
                      Icon='/IMDC ePub Maker;component/EPUB-50.png.ico'>
    <controls:MetroWindow.DataContext>
        <viewModel:MainViewModel />
    </controls:MetroWindow.DataContext>
    <UserControl>
        <UserControl.Resources>
            <ResourceDictionary>
                <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                    <ResourceDictionary Source='/IMDC ePub Maker;component/Resources/Icons.xaml' />
                </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            </ResourceDictionary>
        </UserControl.Resources>
        <Grid>
            <Grid.Background>
                <ImageBrush ImageSource='C:\Users\Erwin\Downloads\EPUB-100.png'
                            Opacity=".5" />
            </Grid.Background>
            <Image Name="imgLogo"
                   Height="53"
                   HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                   Stretch="Fill"
                   VerticalAlignment="Top"
                   Width="160"
                   Margin="2,5,0,0"
                   Source='D:\Erwin\_Projects\_WPF Apps\DBNL Delivery Details\DBNL Delivery Details\Images\logo.png' />
            <Label Height="28"
                   HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                   Margin="165,19,0,0"
                   VerticalAlignment="Top"
                   FontSize="14"
                   Content="{Binding ProgramName}" />
            <Label Height="28"
                   HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                   Margin="167,37,0,0"
                   VerticalAlignment="Top"
                   FontSize="9"
                   Content="{Binding ProgramVersion}" />
            <GroupBox Header="Input Path"
                      Height="79"
                      HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                      Margin="12,71,0,0"
                      VerticalAlignment="Top"
                      Width="540"
                      IsEnabled="{Binding IsNotBusy}">
                <Grid>
                    <TextBox Height="23"
                             HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                             Margin="6,6,0,0"
                             VerticalAlignment="Top"
                             Width="462"
                             controls:TextBoxHelper.Watermark="Input Files"
                             controls:TextBoxHelper.ClearTextButton="True"
                             Text="{Binding PathM.InputPath, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, NotifyOnValidationError=True, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}" />
                    <Button Height="23"
                            HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                            Margin="473,7,0,0"
                            VerticalAlignment="Top"
                            Width="49"
                            Command='{Binding BrowseDirectory}'
                            Opacity=".7">
                        <Rectangle Width='15'
                                   Height='15'
                                   Fill='{DynamicResource BlackBrush}'>
                            <Rectangle.OpacityMask>
                                <VisualBrush Stretch='Fill'
                                             Visual='{StaticResource appbar_folder_open }' />
                            </Rectangle.OpacityMask>
                        </Rectangle>
                    </Button>
                </Grid>
            </GroupBox>
            <GroupBox x:Name='groupBox'
                      Header='ePub Details'
                      HorizontalAlignment='Left'
                      Margin='12,155,0,0'
                      VerticalAlignment='Top'
                      Height='170'
                      Width='540'
                      IsEnabled="{Binding IsNotBusy}">
                <Grid>
                    <ComboBox HorizontalAlignment='Left'
                              VerticalAlignment='Top'
                              Width='250'
                              Margin='268,99,0,0'
                              Height='19'
                              controls:TextBoxHelper.Watermark="Choose Validator"
                              ItemsSource="{Binding EPubM.JavaePubValidatorList, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, NotifyOnValidationError=True, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}"
                              SelectedValue="{Binding EPubM.JavaePubValidator}"
                              Opacity=".8" />
                    <TextBox HorizontalAlignment='Left'
                             Height='23'
                             Margin='10,37,0,0'
                             VerticalAlignment='Top'
                             Width='250'
                             controls:TextBoxHelper.Watermark="Book Title"
                             controls:TextBoxHelper.ClearTextButton="True"
                             Text="{Binding EPubM.BookTitle, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, NotifyOnValidationError=True, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}"
                             Opacity=".8" />
                    <TextBox HorizontalAlignment='Left'
                             Height='23'
                             Margin='10,68,0,0'
                             VerticalAlignment='Top'
                             Width='250'
                             controls:TextBoxHelper.Watermark="Author"
                             controls:TextBoxHelper.ClearTextButton="True"
                             Text="{Binding EPubM.Author, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, NotifyOnValidationError=True, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}"
                             Opacity=".8" />
                    <TextBox HorizontalAlignment='Left'
                             Height='23'
                             Margin='10,99,0,0'
                             VerticalAlignment='Top'
                             Width='250'
                             controls:TextBoxHelper.Watermark="Identifier"
                             controls:TextBoxHelper.ClearTextButton="True"
                             Text="{Binding EPubM.Identifier, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, NotifyOnValidationError=True, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}"
                             Opacity=".8" />
                    <TextBox HorizontalAlignment='Left'
                             Height='23'
                             Margin='268,6,0,0'
                             VerticalAlignment='Top'
                             Width='250'
                             controls:TextBoxHelper.Watermark="ePub Filename"
                             controls:TextBoxHelper.ClearTextButton="True"
                             Text="{Binding EPubM.EpubFileName, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, NotifyOnValidationError=True, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}"
                             Opacity=".8" />
                    <TextBox HorizontalAlignment='Left'
                             Height='23'
                             Margin='268,37,0,0'
                             VerticalAlignment='Top'
                             Width='250
                             '
                             controls:TextBoxHelper.Watermark="Publisher"
                             controls:TextBoxHelper.ClearTextButton="True"
                             Text="{Binding EPubM.Publisher, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, NotifyOnValidationError=True, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}"
                             Opacity=".8" />
                    <ComboBox HorizontalAlignment='Left'
                              VerticalAlignment='Top'
                              Width='250'
                              Margin='268,68,0,0'
                              Height='19'
                              controls:TextBoxHelper.Watermark="Choose Language"
                              ItemsSource="{Binding EPubM.LanguageList, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, NotifyOnValidationError=True, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}"
                              SelectedValue="{Binding EPubM.Language}"
                              Opacity=".8" />
                    <ComboBox HorizontalAlignment='Left'
                              VerticalAlignment='Top'
                              Width='250'
                              Margin='10,6,0,0'
                              Height='19'
                              controls:TextBoxHelper.Watermark="Choose Project"
                              ItemsSource="{Binding PathM.ProjectList, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, NotifyOnValidationError=True, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}"
                              SelectedValue="{Binding PathM.Project}"
                              Opacity=".8" />
                </Grid>
            </GroupBox>
            <Button Content="_Process"
                    Height="40"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                    Margin="454,330,0,0"
                    VerticalAlignment="Top"
                    Width="98"
                    Command="{Binding StartProcess}"
                    IsEnabled="{Binding IsNotBusy}"
                    Opacity=".7" />
            <Label Content='{Binding StatM.ActivityStatus}'
                   HorizontalAlignment='Left'
                   Margin='10,320,0,0'
                   VerticalAlignment='Top'
                   Height='41'
                   Width='343'
                   FontSize="10"
                   FontStyle="Italic" />
            <Label Content='{Binding StatM.DisplayName}'
                   HorizontalAlignment='Left'
                   Margin='10,335,0,0'
                   VerticalAlignment='Top'
                   Height='41'
                   Width='343'
                   FontSize="12"
                   FontWeight="Medium" />
            <controls:MetroProgressBar Height="19"
                                       IsIndeterminate="True"
                                       Margin="16,351,126,10"
                                       Visibility="{Binding StatM.OnOffProgBar}"
                                       Foreground='Brown' />
            <Button HorizontalAlignment='Left'
                    Margin='491,23,0,0'
                    VerticalAlignment='Top'
                    Width='47'
                    Command='{Binding About, Mode=OneWay}'
                    IsEnabled='{Binding IsNotBusy}'
                    Opacity=".7">
                <Rectangle Width='15'
                           Height='15'
                           Fill='{DynamicResource BlackBrush}'>
                    <Rectangle.OpacityMask>
                        <VisualBrush Stretch='Fill'
                                     Visual='{StaticResource appbar_book_perspective_help}' />
                    </Rectangle.OpacityMask>
                </Rectangle>
            </Button>
        </Grid>
    </UserControl>
</controls:MetroWindow>
```

MainViewModel

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Windows.Input;
using IMDC_ePub_Maker.Class;
using IMDC_ePub_Maker.Command;
using IMDC_ePub_Maker.Model;
using IMDC_ePub_Maker.Properties;
using IMDC_ePub_Maker.View;
using MessageBox = System.Windows.MessageBox;

namespace IMDC_ePub_Maker.ViewModel
{
    public class MainViewModel : BaseViewModel
    {
        private PathModel _pathM;
        private bool _isNotBusy;
        private DelegateCommand _about;
        private DelegateCommand _browseDirectory;
        private DelegateCommand _startProcess;
        private StatusModel _statM;
        private EPubModel _ePubM;
        private readonly List<ErrorModel> _errorList;
        private readonly List<ErrorModel> _warningList;


        public MainViewModel()
        {
            PathM = new PathModel();
            StatM = new StatusModel();
            EPubM = new EPubModel();
            _warningList = new List<ErrorModel>();
            StatM.OnOffProgBar = Visibility.Hidden;
            StatM.ActivityStatus = "Idle...";
            StatM.DisplayName = "Waiting for input...";
            IsNotBusy = true;
            _errorList = new List<ErrorModel>();
            _warningList = new List<ErrorModel>();
        }

        public PathModel PathM
        {
            get { return _pathM; }
            set { _pathM = value; OnPropertyChanged("PathM"); }
        }

        public StatusModel StatM
        {
            get { return _statM; }
            set { _statM = value; OnPropertyChanged("StatM"); }
        }

        public EPubModel EPubM
        {
            get { return _ePubM; }
            set { _ePubM = value; OnPropertyChanged("EPubM"); }
        }

        public bool IsNotBusy
        {
            get { return _isNotBusy; }
            set { _isNotBusy = value; OnPropertyChanged("IsNotBusy"); }
        }

        public static string ProgDesc => Global.Description;

        public static string ProgramAuthor => Global.Author;

        public static string ProgramExe => Global.ProgramExe + " -- " + Global.ProgramVersion + " (" + Global.ProgramVerDate + ")";

        public static string ProgramName => Global.ProgramName;

        public static string ProgramVersion => (Global.ProgramVersion + " - " + Global.ProgramVerDate);

        public ICommand BrowseDirectory
        {
            get
            {
                _browseDirectory = new DelegateCommand(() =>
                {
                    var dialog = new FolderBrowserDialog
                    {
                        Description = Resources.BrowseDirectory,
                        SelectedPath = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory
                    };
                    if (dialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                    {
                        PathM.InputPath = dialog.SelectedPath;
                    }
                });
                return _browseDirectory;
            }
        }

        public ICommand About
        {
            get
            {
                _about = new DelegateCommand(() =>
                {
                    var about = new About();
                    about.Show();
                });
                return _about;
            }
        }

        public ICommand StartProcess
        {
            get
            {
                _startProcess = new DelegateCommand(() =>
                {
                    if ((PathM.ErrorList.Count > 0) && EPubM.ErrorList.Count > 0) return;
                    if ((string.IsNullOrEmpty(EPubM.JavaePubValidator)) || (string.IsNullOrEmpty(EPubM.Language))) return;
                    var worker = new BackgroundWorker();
                    worker.DoWork += DoWork;
                    worker.RunWorkerCompleted += RunWorkerCompleted;
                    IsNotBusy = false;
                    StatM.OnOffProgBar = Visibility.Visible;
                    try
                    {
                        worker.RunWorkerAsync();
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString(), Global.ProgramName, MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
                    }
                });
                return _startProcess;
            }
        }



        private void DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                StatM.DisplayName = string.Concat(EPubM.EpubFileName, ".epub").Replace("_", "__");
                StatM.ActivityStatus = "I'm working on it...";
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
                if (Directory.Exists(PathModel.OutputPath))
                {
                    DeleteDirectory(PathModel.OutputPath);
                }
                var htmlfiles =
                    new List<string>(Directory.EnumerateFiles(PathM.InputPath, "*.html", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly));               
                Global.DocAuthor = EPubM.Author;
                Global.DocTitle = EPubM.BookTitle;
                Global.Language = EPubM.Language;
                Global.Publisher = EPubM.Publisher;
                Global.Identifier = EPubM.Identifier;
                Global.EPubJavaValidator = EPubM.JavaePubValidator;
                Global.EPubName = EPubM.EpubFileName;
                Global.SupportPath = PathModel.SupportPath;
                Global.ValidatorPath = PathModel.ValidatorPath;             
                Global.ImageLoc = PathM.ImagePath;
                Global.InputPath = PathM.InputPath;
                var report = new Report();
                try
                {                   
                    foreach (var html in htmlfiles)
                    {
                        StatM.ActivityStatus = "Checking Garbage Character...";
                        StatM.DisplayName = Path.GetFileName(html)?.Replace("_", "__");
                        CheckGarbageCharacters(html);
                        Thread.Sleep(300);
                        StatM.ActivityStatus = "Checking Multiple spacess...";
                        StatM.DisplayName = Path.GetFileName(html)?.Replace("_", "__");
                        CheckMultipleSpaces(html);
                        Thread.Sleep(300);
                        StatM.ActivityStatus = "Checking Tab Data...";
                        StatM.DisplayName = Path.GetFileName(html)?.Replace("_", "__");
                        CheckTabData(html);
                        Thread.Sleep(300);
                    }
                    if (_errorList.Count <= 0)
                    {
                        Directory.CreateDirectory(PathModel.OutputPath);
                        StatM.ActivityStatus = "Creating ePub...";
                        StatM.DisplayName = string.Concat(EPubM.EpubFileName, ".epub");
                        EPubMaker.CreateEpub(PathM.InputPath, PathModel.OutputPath);
                        CheckCover();
                        if (_warningList.Count > 0)
                        {
                            report.CreateReport(_warningList, Path.Combine(PathModel.OutputPath, string.Concat(EPubM.EpubFileName, ".edt")), PathM.Project);
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Directory.CreateDirectory(PathModel.OutputPath);
                        report.CreateReport(_errorList, Path.Combine(PathModel.OutputPath, string.Concat(EPubM.EpubFileName, ".edt")), PathM.Project);
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception exception)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(exception.ToString(), "Error", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
                    Environment.Exit(110);
                }

            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(exception.ToString(), "Error", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
                Environment.Exit(110);
            }
        }

        private void RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            var path = Path.Combine(PathModel.OutputPath, string.Concat("~", EPubM.EpubFileName));
            if (Directory.Exists(Path.Combine(PathModel.OutputPath, string.Concat("~", EPubM.EpubFileName))))
            {
                DeleteDirectory(path);
            }
            ResetValues();
            StatM.OnOffProgBar = Visibility.Hidden;
            IsNotBusy = true;
            StatM.ActivityStatus = "";
            StatM.DisplayName = "Processing Complete!";
        }

        private static void DeleteDirectory(string path)
        {
            foreach (var directory in Directory.GetDirectories(path))
            {
                DeleteDirectory(directory);
            }
            try
            {
                Directory.Delete(path, true);
            }
            catch (IOException)
            {
                Directory.Delete(path, true);
            }
            catch (UnauthorizedAccessException)
            {
                Directory.Delete(path, true);
            }
        }

        private void ResetValues()
        {
            PathM.InputPath = string.Empty;
            EPubM.BookTitle = string.Empty;
            EPubM.Author = string.Empty;
            EPubM.EpubFileName = string.Empty;
            EPubM.Identifier = string.Empty;
            EPubM.JavaePubValidator = string.Empty;
            EPubM.Language = string.Empty;
            EPubM.Publisher = string.Empty;
        }

    }
}
```

Excel file

[image: excel]

Excel VM

```
public static DataTable ReadInventory(string excelPath)
    {
        string cmdText = "select * from [Search Result$]";
        string connectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OleDb.4.0;\r\n                              Data Source=" + excelPath + ";Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;";
        DataTable table = new DataTable();
        OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);
        OleDbCommand command = null;
        OleDbDataReader reader = null;
        connection.Open();
        try
        {
            command = new OleDbCommand(cmdText, connection);
            reader = command.ExecuteReader();
            table.Load(reader);
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            throw new Exception(exception.ToString());
        }
        finally
        {
            command.Dispose();
            reader.Dispose();
            connection.Close();
            connection.Dispose();
        }
        return table;
    }
```

Comment: Where is your code in VM which reads the excel file?

Comment: i will edit and include it in my question.

Comment: what is your actual problem?

Comment: i don't know how to make automatically input the content of the excel in their respective textbox in WPF Fom. I have some idea on how to do that, but I want to do it  MVVM pattern since my app is based on MVVM

Comment: is there any one knows how to do it..